# Why does TeXShop need 4GB of RAM?

Tags: editors, texshop

TeXShop runs sslloowww on my MacBook, when I look at Activity Monitor it has 4.25 GB. Why? I've only got one file open (it has a few hundred lines). Isn't 4GB a lot for what is, in essence, a glorified text editor?

Comment: Are you running the latest version (and which OS version are you using?) My TeXShop is using 262 MB with about 14 windows open. There was a memory leak in versions < 3.66 which was fixed in subsequent versions.

Comment: @AlanMunn About the same as I, with eleven windows, one a 13000 line file.

Comment: hmm. Im on 3.59. I will upgrade, Thanks,

Comment: I once had a similar problem - I mean, it was just how the editor handled the file (s) (and we assume that there is no garbage on your PC and no powerful programs are running in the background). I would try in your place to empty the RAM or just restart the computer and if possible download updates (especially for the program). But it is true that there are development environments that run very fast and very error-free, and do so without using a lot of resources.

Comment: @AlanMunn: TeXShop defintely has a memory leak: [TeXShop Using 24GB](https://i.imgur.com/AesG499.png). This is with TeXShop 4.01 on MacOS 10.13.4.  I have found that if you restart things are ok (for a while).  I believe the problem occurs when you open and close many files. Having one big file continually open does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill Have you reported this? I haven't encountered this myself. But I'm still using 10.12.6 as my OS.

Comment: @AlanMunn: No I haven't as I assumed it was a know issue and am pretty sure it was there in earlier versions of the OS. I will email Richard. I guess most people don't open and close numerous small files like I do.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of TeXShop earlier than 3.66 were known to have a memory leak. There were a couple of different fixes to the leak that came out in subsequent versions.  The current version (4.01 as of this writing), should not have the memory leak. See [version history](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/version.html).

Peter Grill suggests in the comments that there may still be a memory leak in the current version. I have no direct evidence of this myself. If the problem persists after updating, it might be best to contact Dick Koch the developer directly with the issue.

Comment: There used to be a very big memory leak in pre-Sierra versions of Mac OS X, precisely in PDFKit, which TeXShop wasn’t responsible for.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, the changes in PDKkit will responsible for most of the problems. Although most (not all) crashes have disappeared, there are still some lingering display problems with pdfKit.

Comment: I use a TeXShop v4.77  .engine which uses `-output-directory=`. The .pdf an .aux files are in a separate directory. I open the pdf via Skim. Thus, TeXShop never sees the pdf nor the aux files. Today, I saw that TeXShop memory usage was at 28GB. Since then it dropped and upon restart it is aroung 5GB. I have emailed Richard the details so am hoping it gets looked into. I have seen memory issues since Sierra when Apple switched to their pdfkit. I had assumed it was related to the pdf, but my experiement show that that is not necessarily the case.